# docker port exposing issue

Tags: python, docker, flask, containers, port

I have a flask application that I'm trying to dockerize but the ports are not getting exposed properly.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.7

LABEL Name=testAPP Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 5000

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Using pip:
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD ["application.py" ,"runserver","-h 0.0.0.0"]
```

Docker Build is successful:

```
docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t testAPP .
```

Docker Run is building the image successfully

```
docker run -device -expose 5000:5000 testAPP
```

Also tried,

```
docker run --rm -d -p 443:443/tcp -p 5000:5000/tcp -p 80:80/tcp testAPP
```

But when I try to access the site it throws an error

[site can't be reached error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orziA.png)

Flask App(Inside the APP)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

On Execution of the command

```
Docker container ps

CONTAINER ID     IMAGE        COMMAND      CREATED          STATUS    PORTS      NAMES
 8724cdb38e14    testAPP   "/entrypoint.sh pyth…" 15 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds    80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp  funny_galois
```

Comment: Do the container logs say anything?  Can you include the actual code that writes out the text `site can't be reached error`?  Is the process inside the container actually listening on port 5000?  Is the extra space in the `-h` option confusing it?

Comment: container logs say, the app is running in http://0.0.0.0:5000/, but when I try to access the same in chrome, I get Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: 0.0.0.0 isn't a valid IP address you can connect to; it's a special address used by the low-level APIs to say "listen on all interfaces".  You should be able to use the host's IP address given what you've shown.  (Note that your `docker ps` output doesn't match the `docker run` command you've shown, though.)

Comment: I have changed the IP to 127.0.0.1:5000 but still the same response. I have updated container ps command above

Answer (score 0):

Defining a port as *exposed* doesn’t publish the port by itself. Try with the flag *-p* , like:

> -p container_port:local_port

example:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ~/Code/PYTHON/ttftt-recipes-manager:/app python_dev
```

But before running try to check if there is something else that already running on the specified port like:

```
lsof -i :PORTNUM
```

and after with something like:

```
docker logs my_container
```

Comment: tried publishing too, but still the same error
docker run --rm -d --publish 5000:5000 -p 443:443/tcp -p 80:80/tcp testAPP

Comment: seems your server didnt start correctly, maybe because of your CMD line try something like `CMD ["python3", "application.py" ,"runserver","-h 0.0.0.0"]` did you try to see container logs ?

Comment: If I try with python 3 in CMD, it throws error python can't be found, but when I try it with python and remove ENTRYPOINT, I get a different error,

s.bind(server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: ok then its a python error and not a docker one , try to make your flask app run on 0.0.0.0 in your code and remove "-h 0.0.0.0" from RUN, how do you run it locally ?

Comment: otherwise you can try this `["application.py" ,"runserver","-h", "0.0.0.0"]` your error is because you didnt pass a valable port argument to your application

Comment: I have resolved python error and changed the URL to 0.0.0.0. In the docker file, I have updated CMD ["python","application.py" ,"run"]. now the container is getting created and when I access the  container logs, it says the app is running at  http://0.0.0.0:5000/ but when i access it still says site can't be reached

Comment: can you please provide the output of `docker container ps` please ?

Comment: you have something running on port 8000.... , and your entry point shouldnt "/entrypoint.sh pyth…" check on the previous port, stop the running container, rebuild your image and run it again, you messed up a bit with your previous tries i guess

Comment: port 8000 is locked with com.docker.backed.exe and UAC virtualization is not allowed for it and also I tried rebuilding the image, but the entry-point is the same

Comment: @GowthamBabu Did you ever figure out an answer, I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're mapping your localhost port to the container's port

docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 your_image

And once you're application is in the container, you want to run your app with the host set to 0.0.0.0

Comment: I have updated the post, and I have changed the flask app to point 8000 port and still, I'm getting the same response.

Comment: You're completely missing the point of my answer. You can use whatever port you want (obviously not ANY port but you get the idea), but you have to specify the localhost port that needs to be mapped.